# Why rows get changeg after UPDATE in table? PostreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

My initial table

[image]

Table after update a version with
`select * from "table";`

Comment: I'm not really a PostgreSQL guy myself, but generally whatever primary key / default indexing is applied on a table will determine the sort order of rows (if you don't include any specific ORDER BY in your SELECT statement).  In this case, my guess would be that the "version" column is a factor in this particular table's default sort order

Comment: It would be useful for everybody to know the update you made, at least. Update a version with `select * from "table"` is not that self explanatory as you can think.

Comment: The rows get changed because update changes content of some rows. What do you exactly mean?

Comment: I believe the specific question that the OP is asking is, "Why, after updating the version number of the row with ID = 3, did the order in which the rows appear (doing a simple SELECT * FROM table) change?"

Comment: @ego_xxx - this question could be asked in a better way, so that it is clear to others exactly what the answer is that you are seeking.  Also, it's better to include your sample data as text within the question, rather than images

Comment: @craig. Rows are by default unordered, PK/indexing does not enter into it. If you want an `ORDER` you need to specify it with an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the row order changed is PostgreSQL's implementation of multiversioning.

When a row is updated in PostgreSQL, the actual table entry ("tuple", to use the jargon) is not modified. Instead, a new version of the row is inserted into the table, and the old version is marked invalid (I am simplifying here). Concurrent readers can still access the old tuple to get the original data. When nobody needs the old tuple any more, it is reclaimed by autovacuum.

In your case, the new tuple was added at the end of the table. So if it looks as if an `UPDATE` moved a row, it is because that's what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

As a formal definition, a Relational DBMS is build on relational algebra wich is a branch of mathematics running in the field of the set theory...

In a mathematical set, there is absoluty no default order beacause set are "bags" and belongings in bags will be "blend" when travelling... (Just go see the contents of your girlfriend's purse to convince yourself!)

This is the reason why there is a **ORDER BY** clause in SQL SELECT statement, because a RDBMS can never make sure that any order will be respected! And the placement of the returned rows can change at any time!

Comment: pretty sure, he has been using a heap table. In that case, the update caused row 3 to move o the end of the heap due to rewriting it.

Comment: @TarekSalha: even if Postgres did have something else than "heap tables" (i.e. clustered index), it would still not _guarantee_ a certain sort order without an `order by` (think of parallel execution or synchronized seq scans)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are true... Even in clustered indexes like Microsoft SQL Server do, there is no default constant ordering. Because the engine does it in multithreading, one arbitrary thread will finish first and one last, rarely the same at every execution... So the final concatenate results will have an arbitrary order. There is many other situation that give the same behaviour.

Comment: @Tarek_Salha yes,  beacuse the only way that PostGreSQL does an UPDATE is to create systematically a new row. This "bizarre" PG behaviour is a due to the bad implementation of MVCC. See my paper about those problems... http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/